# Parsing LocalDate in Java: What's the pattern for "March 26 2020"

Tags: java, java-time, date-parsing

I can't seem to come up with a pattern for "March 26 2020" (no comma). Can someone help? I've tried `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd yyyy")` and `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy")`.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
    String strDate = "March 26 2020";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd uuuu");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtf);
    System.out.println(date);
```

On my computer this throws

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text 'March 26 2020' could not be parsed at index 0

Expected output was

> ```
> 2020-03-26
> ```

With `MMM` in the format pattern instead the exception is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the pattern, `MMMM dd uuuu` with `Locale.ENGLISH`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "March 26 2020";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtf);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-03-26
```

Comment: `Locale.ENGLISH` is a spot on!

Comment: I think `Locale.US` works as well. `Locale.ROOT`, interestingly, does not.

Comment: Interesting indeed, @MCEmperor, thanks. On my Java 11 `Locale.ROOT` produces and expects `Mar 26 2020`. Might seem like a bug to me, though there might be some reason that I can’t understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM' 'dd' 'yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Worked for me just fine, Output:

```
December 10 2020
```

Comment: You do not need to specify the space between `MMMM` and `dd` or between `dd` and `yyyy` explicitly using `' '`. You can simply put the space without using single quotes.

Comment: I've seen sometimes it could make a difference

Comment: @MichaelGantman No, for a space never. Some do recommend the single quotes anyway, it’s probably a matter of taste.

Comment: It’s even in [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), @ArvindKumarAvinash: *… it is recommended to use single quotes around all characters that you want to output directly to ensure that future changes do not break your application.*

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable information. I'm not sure whether they have assumed that space characters will always be parsed without quotes or whether the documentation needs to be updated. They say *Any non-letter character, other than '[', ']', '{', '}', '#' and the single quote will be output directly.*

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I am not sure either. And I most often do not follow this particular recommendation.